Git failing for android.googlesource.com
I compiling crDroid A14 for an unofficial device (Pixel 4a). They have moved to A15 recently, I am compiling A14, and many official devices are still compiling releases for A14.
I'm having a git issue. I deleted and refreshed and am still getting the following errors.
type h~/android/crDroid$ repo sync;
Fetching: 41% (592/1436) 0:13 | 4 jobs | 0:03 device/common @ device/common
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/diamondjohn/android/crDroid/.repo/projects/device/common.git'

device/common:
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/diamondjohn/android/crDroid/.repo/projects/device/common.git'
device/common: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/diamondjohn/android/crDroid/.repo/projects/device/common.git'
error: Cannot fetch device/common from https://android.googlesource.com/device/common
Fetching: 41% (593/1436) 0:13 | 4 jobs | 0:03 device/common @ device/common
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/diamondjohn/android/crDroid/.repo/projects/external/tagsoup.git'

platform/external/tagsoup:
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/diamondjohn/android/crDroid/.repo/projects/external/tagsoup.git'
platform/external/tagsoup: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/diamondjohn/android/crDroid/.repo/projects/external/tagsoup.git'
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/tagsoup from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tagsoup
Fetching: 41% (602/1436) 0:13 | 4 jobs | 0:03 device/common @ device/common
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/diamondjohn/android/crDroid/.repo/projects/external/tensorflow.git'

...etc...
I last did a refresh a few months ago, and all was fine. I also checked, and the revision does exist. https://android.googlesource.com/device/common/+/refs/tags/android-14.0.0_r67
In the manifest
  <remote  name="aosp"
           fetch="https://android.googlesource.com"
           review="android-review.googlesource.com"
           revision="refs/tags/android-14.0.0_r67" />

...snip....

<project path="device/common" name="device/common" groups="pdk-cw-fs,pdk" remote="aosp" />

I had an issue a few years back where the DNS server failed after a while, thinking it was under a DOS. So I added android.googlesource.com to the host files, and it made no difference. And I can access the above after the fail.

Looks more like a problem on your side, you are trying to perform a git fetch of a directory that doesn't belong to a git repo. First you have to clone a repo, then you can execute git fetch on it.

Thanks for your response. I know its on my side, as others are releasing builds. In the past I have forked Github to Github. but from Google source is new to me. Your post implies the only way I can think of, is to manually clone it locally, and maybe upload to github. I am hoping that doing it manually (a clone) and specifically on one repository, may give hints as to what is going wrong. THANKS

FYI / Update:I dont know what the root cause was, but I tried the following.

I was running the old rev revision of repo, so updated to the latest. That FAILED
Adding the IP to hosts. In case it was a DOS block. That FAILED
Reformatting the ROM source (which was the failure) and re-initialising and re-downloading afresh. that FAILED
I tried manually cloning the individual failed repositories. I think that worked for one, but basically FAILED
I created a new VBox Ubuntu PC AND re-initialised the source and THAT WORKED.

So its working now, as I basically started from scratch.
